# Rails and Que jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob, que

Before I use sidekiq but now I decided to move to que and store everything in Postgresql. Because I don't need redis high-perfomance features I wanted to decrease dependency my application from external components. I add gem 'que', installed it and wrote in application.rb:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :que
```

All jobs I inhereted from ActiveJob::Base

But I doesn't understand how to run background task in separate thread like I do it with sidekiq (I run by rake command rake sidekiq:start)

Answer (score 0):

There is an executable `que` available. So, you just need to run `que`. To learn more about options run `que -h`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Que.mode = :async` to enable background workers.

You'll want to place that in an initializer file.